# Add random characters to end of file path

Tags: php

I have this

```
$resizeObj -> saveImage('images/'.$pic, 90);
```

and I want to append random characters at the end of file name in order to prevent duplicate names using somethign like this:

```
    function genRandomString() {
    $length = 10;
    $characters = ’0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz’;
    $string = ”;    

    for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
        $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))];
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Whta is the best way to incorporate this into `$resizeObj`

Comment: Is concurrency an issue? You could use `microtime()` if you're not planning on adding loads of images at the same time?

Comment: If you want a random string, why not just use `uniqid()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not save random string. Just append a unique string (eg. uniqid()) when you present the image.

Comment: So if I do `$pic=uniqid(($_FILES['photo']['name']));`  the uniqid is appended after the .jpg extention.  How do I get it to be a prefix to the name?

Comment: @RonnieT Sorry, I misunderstood. What you want is just $pic=uniqid() . $extention

Comment: Ended up with defining `$id = uniqid();` then passing $id into $pic `$pic=$id.($_FILES['photo']['name']);` since I needed the same uniqid used multiple times in the document. Thanks for the help man.

Answer (score 1):

```
$pathinfo = pathinfo($pic);
$pic = sprintf("%s%s.%s", $pathinfo['basename'], getRandomString(), $pathinfo['extension']);
$resizeObj -> saveImage('images/'.$pic, 90);
```